# BASH - Globbing expressions with square brackets : [...-...]

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm posting here because I misunderstood something about bash globbing expressions. I read the POSIX and the definition of this specific type of expression (the ones with the square brackets), and while testing, I did that test :

```
bash-3.2$ ls
a.out    c.cou    tab_maker.c

bash-3.2$ ls [!c-t]
ls: [!c-t]: No such file or directory

bash-3.2$ ls [!c-t]*
a.out

bash-3.2$ ls [!c-to]*
a.out

bash-3.2$ ls [!cv-to]*
a.out    tab_maker.c

bash-3.2$
```

What I don't understand is how does bash interpret this command ? When I do `ls [!c-t]*`, bash catches a.out only (which is logical to me), but why does it catch tab_maker.c with the last test ? Is there something I should know or is it just undefined behavior ?

Comment: Can you please paste the code to the question instead of linking to a screenshot?

Comment: It's done sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing matches `[v-t]`, as there are no characters between `v` and `t`. `[!cv-to]` is therefore equivalent to `[!co]`.

Try `[t-v]` instead.

Comment: Hmm, I really don't understand why it does that. Is there some sort of priority when I type more than 1 character on each side of the dash between the brackets ?

Comment: Between `t` and `v`, there are `t, u, v`. Between `v` and `t`, there's nothing.  The character before `-` must precede alphabetically the one after it (or be the same) in order to match anything.

Comment: Yep I understood that, the thing that I don't understand is why it is considering `[!cv-to]` equivalent to `[!co]` ? The thing that I don't understand is what are the rules for that type of command ? For example, when I do that `[!ct-vo]`, is it considering only `t-v` and not the `c` and the `o` or is it doing something else ?

Comment: @S_Mindcore: In `[!ct-vo]`, `t-v` is expanded to `tuv`, so it's equivalent to `[!ctuvo]`.

Comment: Oh OK I get it now !! Thanks a lot :D